# What is the mistake in my matrix power formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, exponentiation, diagonalization

I am working through a Linear Algebra practice test and got stuck on the following question:

*Let A = \begin{matrix}5, -1\\-1, 5\end{matrix}  Compute a formula for A^k where k is a positive integer.  Your answer should be a single matrix.*

I calculated A^2 and got \begin{matrix}26, -10\\-10, 26\end{matrix} but figured repeated multiplication was not the way to go, so I calculated A's eigenvalues/eigenvectors to diagonalize it, yielding \begin{matrix}4, 0\\0, 6\end{matrix} and the change of basis matrix \begin{matrix}1, -1\\1, 1\end{matrix}  Then I inverted the change of basis matrix to \begin{matrix}1/2, 1/2\\-1/2, 1/2\end{matrix}

I multiplied \begin{matrix}4^k, 0\\0, 6^k\end{matrix} by this inverse on the left to get the putative solution \begin{matrix}(4^k)/2, (6^k)/2\\-(4^k)/2, (6^k)/2\end{matrix} but this does not produce the above result I initially got by computing A^2.  Where does my mistake lie?

Comment: you need to multiply the diagonal matrix on the left and right by the change of basis matrix and it's inverse. It would help if you showed in math exactly what you did, also. Oh, and repeat multiplication of matrices is almost never the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As qbert wrote in his comment, you’ve gotten the change-of basis matrix and its inverse in the wrong order. I often made the same mistake until I memorized the “bulk” matrix version of the eigenvector equation $AP=P\Lambda$. In this case, you’re going from the diagonal matrix $\Lambda^k$ to $A^k$, so the $P$ on the left-hand side of the equation has to move to the right: $A^k=P\Lambda^kP^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}
\right) = I
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
4 & 0 \\
0 & 6
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
5 & -1 \\
-1 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
4 & 0 \\
0 & 6
\end{array}
\right)^n
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
5 & -1 \\
-1 & 5
\end{array}
\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

To understand what the linear transformations are actual doing, it's better to include the basis on which the linear transformation is working into our calculations.

In the question, $A = \begin{pmatrix}5 & -1 \\ -1 & 5\end{pmatrix}$.  It is diagonalised to give $D = [\mathsf{L}_A]_\beta = \begin{pmatrix}4 & 0\\0 & 6\end{pmatrix}$, where $\beta$ is the orthogonal basis formed by the eigenvectors $\beta = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$.  This gives $P = [\mathsf{Id}]_\beta^\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, where $\gamma$ represents the standard basis.

$P^{-1}$ is actually the change of basis matrix from $\gamma$ to $\beta$.

$$P^{-1} = [\mathsf{Id}]_\gamma^\beta = \begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 1/2 \\ -1/2 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}$$

From this, we see that $D^k = [\mathsf{L}_{A^k}]_\beta$.

The last equation in the question body is obtained by multiplying $D^k$ on the left by $P^{-1}$.  When we include the bases into our writing, it becomes
$$P^{-1} D^k = [\mathsf{Id}]_\gamma^\beta [\mathsf{L}_{A^k}]_\beta,$$
which *doesn't* make sense.  To find $A^k$, we can write
$$A^k = [\mathsf{L}_{A^k}]_\gamma = [\mathsf{Id}]_\beta^\gamma [\mathsf{L}_{A^k}]_\beta [\mathsf{Id}]_\gamma^\beta = P D^k P^{-1}.$$
It's easier to compute $\mathsf{L}_A$ with respect to $\beta$ (diagonalised) than to $\gamma$ (not diagonal), so we first apply a change of basis matrix from $\gamma$ to $\beta$, so that we can carry out $\mathsf{L}_{A^k}$ easily, then we convert output back to a vector with coordinates with respect to $\gamma$.